# Merge two based yaml with indentation in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to merge two yamls in jenkins file (.Jenkinsfile)

```
def runConf = """
fail_fast: false
tests:
  - ABC:
"""
print(runConf)

def defaultRunConfig = """
test:
  - ABC.json
  - DEF.json
Seconds: 60
Type: dynamic
"""

def runConfigObj
runConfigObj = readYaml([text:defaultRunConfig])
String time = defaultRunConfig.Seconds.toString()
echo ("Duration for run: " +time)

def runConfigBase
runConfigBase = readYaml([text:runConf])

Map<Object, Object> runConfiguration = [:]
runConfiguration.putAll(runConfigBase)
print(runConfiguration)

for (tests in runConfigObj.test) {
    print(runConfigObj.test)
    runConfiguration.put(runConfigObj.test)
}
runConfiguration['Seconds'] = runConfigObj.Seconds.toString()
runConfiguration['Type'] = runConfigObj.Type
```

Expectation is to get something like:

```
fail_fast: false
  tests:
    - ABC:
        test:
          - ABC.json
          - DEF.json
        Seconds: 60
        Type: dynamic
```

But I am getting below Error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values:
```

Tried looking into options like MAP in groovy but not able to resolve the issue

How to avoid such an error? I am new to groovy, any help is much appreciated

Comment: The error you posted says that there are no versions of `Map.put()` that take only one parameter.
The line
`runConfiguration.put(runConfigObj.test)`
maybe should be
`runConfiguration.put('test', runConfigObj.test)` or, to match the syntax you use later `runConfiguration['test'] = runConfigObj.test`

Comment: also looks like you're trying to add whole array of `runConfigObj.test` instead of separate element which is `test`.

Comment: @SA296 The error says that there are no versions of `LinkedHashMap.put()` that take only one parameter. The problem is on the line `runConfiguration.put(runConfigObj.test)`.  `runConfiguration` is a `Map`. I think my earlier comment was wrong about the solution - I think the first problem is that you are using the for loop on the wrong variable. Certainly I find it confusing that `runConf` is parsed into `runConfigBase` and `defaultRunConfig` is parsed into `runConfObj`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add an array of "tests" as values to the key `test` into a map object of `runConfiguration`, then it should be something like this:

```
runConfiguration['test']=[]
for (test in runConfigObj) {
  runConfiguration['test'].add(test)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesnt work, Below is the outcome of it:
`[test:[
, t, e, s, t, :, 
,  ,  , -,  , A, B, C, ., j, s, o, n, 
,  ,  , -,  , D, E, F, ., j, s, o, n, 
, S, e, c, o, n, d, s, :,  , 6, 0, 
, T, y, p, e, :,  , d, y, n, a, m, i, c, 
]]`